# Error: Cannot convert value of type '(_, _) -> Void' to expected argument type '((UIAlertAction) -> Void)?'

Tags: ios, swift, delete-row, uialertcontroller

I have a button created in my `Main.storyboard`, which has a name (a `var`) named `deleteButton`. This button is in each cell.

When the user presses the button, an alert pops up to confirm the deletion. Here is the code.

```
@IBAction func deletePinpoint(sender: UIButton) {

    let  alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Delete pinpoint", message: "Do you want to delete this pinpoint?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action, indexPath) -> Void in

        if let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate)?.managedObjectContext {
            let pinpointToDelete = self.fetchResultController.objectAtIndexPath(sender.tag) as! Pinpoints
            managedObjectContext.deleteObject(pinpointToDelete)

            do {
                try managedObjectContext.save()
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }))

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))

    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

In the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, I have declared this line:

```
cell.deleteButton.tag = indexPath.row
```

I get the error on the 3rd line (starting with `alertController.addAction`) saying:

> Cannot convert value of type '(_, _) -> Void' to expected argument type '((UIAlertAction) -> Void)?'

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The handler's parameter of `UIAlertAction` constructor, takes the selected action object as its only parameter.

Instead of this:

```
alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action, indexPath) -> Void in
```

you will want this:

```
alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (alert:UIAlertAction) -> Void in
```

Comment: That error then goes, and I get the error on `(sender.tag)` saying **Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'NSIndexPath'**.

Comment: you have to create a NSIndexPath object to pass to objectAtIndexPath. let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: sender.tag, inSection: 0) then set the indexpath to objectAtIndexPath(indexPath)